# Как оптимально работать с таблицей?

Tags: android, сортировка, list, filter

Объясню на примере автомобилей.
У меня есть таблица в CSV с большим количество столбцов и строк. Первые столбцы (для фильтра сортировки) - Тип (легковая, джип, грузовая), Производитель (ВАЗ, Порш, Форд), далее столбцы с параметрами - Объем, Привод, Цвет и т.д.
В программе нужен будет режим фильтра и режим подбора.
Допустим есть 90 строк в них 30 позиций каждого Типа, в каждом Типе по 10 позиций каждого производителя.

Режим фильтра: из таблицы берутся все уникальные Типы и передаются в Spinner. После выбора в выпадающем списке например легковая, во второй Spinner заводятся все Производители у которых столбец Тип - легковая.

Режим подбора: из таблицы берутся все уникальные Типы и передаются в Spinner. Выбирается Тип и задаются некоторые параметры из других столбцов. После этого происходит подбор из таблицы по заданным критериям.
Похожую задачу я когда-то решал, но все было колхозно-кустарным способом. Теперь хочется более правильного подхода.

Как я вижу решение: создать класс Автомобили с полями для всех столбцов. При открытии активити будет считываться-парситься таблица и в объекте Автомобили создаваться коллекция всех строк таблицы. В классе создать какие то функции возвращающие фильтрованные куски коллекции, уникальные списки и т.д.
Ну и результат в список упаковывается.
Подскажите какими методами и что лучше использовать?
Брать просто массивы, хэш, мэп, как быстрее фильтровать/отбирать и т.д.

Comment: ты просто хочешь хранить все данные в csv-файле? и руками их сортировать?

Comment: @strangeqargo получается да. CSV у меня уже есть, вопрос как с ней лучше построить работу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

сходить [сюда](http://mobilesiri.com/android-sqlite-database-tutorial-using-android-studio/) и [сюда](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) либо найти русские учебники по использованию SQLite в Android.

Смысл в том, что вам не нужно  изобретать велосипед (базу данных)  с нуля. Загружаете CSV в бд и имеете всю мощь SQL-запросов, быстрого индексирования и кэширования.